# npx react-native init , not creating project

Tags: react-native, npx

when I run new project command it shows me an error

npx react-native init AwesomProject

npm ERR! Could not install from "computer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\15660" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this : npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
or
use Expo

Comment: this did the trick for me. Saw it on the documentation but though i dont need to run the command first before running the init command.

Thanks for sharing